# Update label in ViewControllerB from ViewControllerA (ViewControllers are both in containers in the same view)

Tags: ios, swift

View controllers A and B are both in containers and together form a single view.
In ViewControllerA I have a button and a label, and in ViewControllerB I have a label.
Both labels are initialised to the number "5".
By pressing on the button in ViewControllerA I would like to add 3 to each label,
i.e. each label should then display "8".
I thought it was as simple as defining a function in ViewControllerB to accept the updated total from ViewControllerA, and to then update the text property of the label in ViewControllerB.
Of course, I get "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value".
Advice/guidance greatly appreciated.

```
import UIKit

class ViewControllerA: UIViewController {

//MARK: Properties
@IBOutlet weak var buttonInViewControllerA: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var labelInViewControllerA: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//MARK: Actions

@IBAction func buttonActionInViewControllerA(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let a: String = String(Int(labelInViewControllerA.text!)! + 3)
    labelInViewControllerA.text = a
    ViewControllerB().add3(value: a)
}
}

class ViewControllerB: UIViewController {

//MARK: Properties
@IBOutlet weak var labelInViewControllerB: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func add3(value: String) {
    self.labelInViewControllerB.text = value
}
}
```

Comment: It is because,  the viewControllerB is not yet loaded. You have to check for the updated value for your label,  when the viewControllerB gets loaded. For a fix, you can add a guard statement to prevent the crash in add3 function like .. guard self.isViewLoaded else { return } before accessing that label

Comment: But ViewControllerB is displayed on the screen and shows the label with value 5.
Does this not mean that it is already loaded ?
(View controllers A and B are both in containers and form part of a single view).
And if I put the following statement in viewDidLoad (in ViewControllerB):
print("Value of label in ViewControllerB is", labelInViewControllerB.text)
then it prints the value "5", which to me says that ViewControllerB is already loaded and the UILabel has been initialised.

Comment: Then just get the reference of viewControllerB, (from viewControllerA, self.parent?.children.last as? viewControllerB). I'm assuming that viewControllerB is the last child

Comment: PS: thanks for your quick response, btw.

Comment: If I'm assuming this would be added to the IBAction in ViewControllerA, what would the whole line look like ?

Comment: Oops - yes, ViewControllerB is the last child.

Comment: This will go inside your IBAction in viewControllerA { (self.parent?.children.last as? viewControllerB) }.add3(value: a) }

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in

```
@IBAction func buttonActionInViewControllerA(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // ...
    ViewControllerB().add3(value: a)
```

}

you create a new instance of `ViewControllerB`. What you need is a reference (property) to the existing one, which you then inform about the change:

```
class ViewControllerA: UIViewController {
    var controllerB:ViewControllerB?

    // ...

    @IBAction func buttonActionInViewControllerA(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // ...
        controllerB?.add3(value: a)
    }
}
```

And dont't forget to set `controllerB` somewhere in your code, e.g.

```
var vcA = ViewControllerA()
var vcB = ViewControllerB()
vcA.controllerB = vcB
// dispaly vcA and vcB
```

Comment: Andreas - MANY thanks.I can see now that I create a new instance  of ViewControllerB (which is why it is empty) !
But I don't understand the purpose of the bottom 4 lines, nor where to put them (presumably in ViewControllerA).

Comment: The last four lines create the ViewControllers, but this is just sample code.Somewhere you create them and put them into the container.

Answer (score 0):

You likely want to use the `Protocol / Delegate` pattern (good idea to read up on it if you're not familiar).

Basically, you create a `Protocol` that defines a function (or functions) that you want to access from "somewhere else."

For example:

```
// protocol / delegate pattern
protocol ABDelegate: class {
    func myButtonWasTapped()
}
```

You want to call `myButtonWasTapped()` from the button tap in `A`, so you create a view controller that "conforms" to this protocol (it has that func), and an `ABDelegate` variable in the view controller where you want to call the func.

Your first thought might be:

*"ok, I'll set that up so `vcB` is the delegate for `vcA` and have my button tap func in `vcA` call the increment func in `vcB` directly."*

That can work, but then the two classes are "too tightly coupled." That is, too dependent on each other.

The better approach is to have your "main" view controller act as an intermediary:

```
// this will be called by the code in ViewControllerA
func myButtonWasTapped() {
    // call func in ViewControllerB
    vcB?.doIncrement()
}
```

So it looks like this:

[image]

The tricky part is getting references to vcA and vcB. Because the embedded view controllers in container views are loaded via `embed segues` you can grab them in `prepare(for segue:...)`:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    // if this is the embedded ViewControllerA
    if let vc = segue.destination as? ViewControllerA {

        // set self as the ABDelegate in ViewControllerA
        vc.theDelegate = self

        // keep a reference in case we want to access it
        self.vcA = vc

    }

    // if this is the embedded ViewControllerB
    if let vc = segue.destination as? ViewControllerB {

        // keep a reference so we can call its doIncrement() func
        self.vcB = vc

    }

}
```

The full code becomes:

```
//
//  ContainerTestViewController.swift
//

import UIKit

// protocol / delegate pattern
protocol ABDelegate: class {
    func myButtonWasTapped()
}

// "main" view controller conforms to ABDelegate protocol
class ContainerTestViewController: UIViewController, ABDelegate {

    var vcA: ViewControllerA?
    var vcB: ViewControllerB?

    // this will be called by the code in ViewControllerA
    func myButtonWasTapped() {
        // call func in ViewControllerB
        vcB?.doIncrement()
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        // if this is the embedded ViewControllerA
        if let vc = segue.destination as? ViewControllerA {

            // set self as the ABDelegate in ViewControllerA
            vc.theDelegate = self

            // keep a reference in case we want to access it
            self.vcA = vc

        }

        // if this is the embedded ViewControllerB
        if let vc = segue.destination as? ViewControllerB {

            // keep a reference so we can call its doIncrement() func
            self.vcB = vc

        }

    }

}

class ViewControllerA: UIViewController {

    var theDelegate: ABDelegate?

    @IBAction func incTapped(_ sender: Any) {

        // call the func in the delegate
        theDelegate?.myButtonWasTapped()

    }

}

class ViewControllerB: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var theLabel: UILabel!

    var theValue = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        theLabel.text = String(theValue)
    }

    func doIncrement() -> Void {
        theValue += 3
        theLabel.text = String(theValue)
    }

}
```